# What do you use for endless pagination within Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Out of curiosity, what do you use for endless pagination within Rails? I looked at the Rails cast on the topic, but it was using an older version of prototype. If you are using endless pagination, please link your site.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised -- here's revised cast. Unfortunately it's not free. But $9 per month totally worth it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi cantbecool,
               endless pagination is used when we want to have a better user experience of fetching data, for eg: rather than clicking on the pagination links and displaying data on a new page, we can fetch sets of data on the same page using will_paginate / kaminari gem and jquery.

there is a good blog on how to implement endless page and hopefully will answer your question.have a look

http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/endless-page-using-jquery-and-will_paginate/

Answer (score 0):

There are two popular gems

1. [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki)
2. [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

We used both in different applications.

Comment: That's pagination - not *endless* pagination (infinite scrolling is probably the better term)